# Sumatra or Espresso More Acidic?

Tags: espresso, ground-coffee, caffeine

I am looking for a less acidic caffeinated drink. Currently Sumatra is the least acidic coffee I’ve found but was wondering if espresso is better since it’s less liquid and has the same amount/more caffeine.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! I don't really understand your question. Sumatra is a place where coffee is grown, but espresso is a way of processing roasted coffee into a drink. Are you asking about acidity of different origins or how brewing methods affect acidity? Or are you asking if the Sumatra bean will be less acidic if made into an espresso compared to regular filter coffee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acidity level of brewed coffee is mainly influenced by three factors:

- Darkness of roast, with lighter roasts generally resulting in higher concentrations of acidic compounds and darker roasts resulting in lower concentrations
- Grind size, with finer grinds enabling greater extraction of acidic compounds (due to greater exposed surface area) and coarser grinds preventing extraction of acidic compounds retained inside the grinds
- Duration of brewing method, with shorter duration brewing methods like espresso generally producing a more acidic brew than longer duration brewing methods like drip or French press

So in general, if you want the least acidic brew you can get, opt for either drip or French press with a dark roast. French press will generally produce a less acidic cup than drip with the same batch of roasted coffee because the grind size difference is quite large.